# Android Studio use one specific language for all other than default

Tags: android-studio, android-location

How do I set Android Studio project to use English translation for all locales other than the default language?  If I have values/ and values-en/ directories, I want all locales other than the default to use the English translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should a bit change your mind and think that all locales should use English translation but in one case (let's say for Spanish) should be no-English. Set `values` as your English directory and `values-xxx` for this as you said `default` case.

If a guy would have a phone with this default locale, he would have no-English translation, otherwise it would be translated to English.

Hope it will help